# $17x+11y \equiv 7 \pmod {29}$ and $13x+10y \equiv 8 \pmod {29}$. What are x and y?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, congruences

Congruency question: if $17x+11y \equiv 7  \pmod {29}$ and $13x+10y \equiv 8 \pmod {29}$, we need to find $x$ and $y$. There may be more than one answer.
Not sure how to go about this; any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Eliminate  $x$ as follows:

$$13(17x+11y-7)-17(13x+10y-8)\equiv0\pmod{29}$$

$$\iff27y\equiv-45\pmod{29}$$

As $(29,3)=1$
$$\implies3y\equiv-5\iff y\equiv3^{-1}\cdot-5$$

As $3\cdot10-1\cdot29=1\implies3^{-1}\equiv10$

$$\implies y\equiv10\cdot-5\equiv8$$

Comment: This solution is fine, but it reads like you are turning in a homework assignment. It would be more helpful and instructive to the person asking the question if you explained what you are doing and why.

Comment: @Nate, Tried updating the logic

Comment: Thanks, I have turned my down-vote into an up-vote appropriately.

Comment: thanks this is really useful. i am just trying to understand the method used. in the penultimate line where does the 16.9 come from?

Comment: I might have made a mistake, but I hink you should have $27y\equiv 16 \pmod{29}$ instead of $27y\equiv 15 \pmod{29}$. I suppose you get this as $(17\cdot 10-13\cdot 11)y \equiv 17\cdot 8-7\cdot13 \pmod{29}$. https://www.google.com/search?q=17%2A8-13%2A7

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Updated

Comment: Still I get $y\equiv-8$ as opposed to your $y\equiv8$. However, now I am not sure where exactly is the problem. Maybe it should be $+45$ instead of $-45$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this a linear system over the field $\Bbb Z_{29}$. The determinat of the matrix is $17\cdot10-11\cdot13=170-143=27\neq 0$ because $29$ does not divide $27$. Then the sulution (mod $29$) is unique.

Now, the inverse of $17$ mod $29$ is $12$, since $17\cdot12=204=29\cdot 7+1$. So multiply the first equation by $12$ to obtain
$$x-13y=-3$$

Then, apply Gaussian elimination in the usual way, but fon't forget that you are working in $\Bbb Z_{29}$.

Answer (score 1):

By subtracting the two congruences you immediately get $4x+y \equiv -1 \pmod{29}$, i.e
$$y\equiv -1-4x \pmod{29}.$$
Plug this into one of the original congruences. You will get a new congruence, which is linear and only has one unknown.

Solve this congruence. You should get $x\equiv9 \pmod{29}$.

And then use the above relation to find the corresponding $x$. You should get $y\equiv-8\equiv21\pmod{29}$.

You can check that this is indeed a solution of the given congruences: 
[(17*9-11*8) mod 29=7](https://www.google.com/search?q=(17*9-11*8)+mod+29) and [(13*9-10*8) mod 29=8](https://www.google.com/search?q=(13*9-10*8)+mod+29).