# How to find solutions for $a$ and $b$ where $9 \equiv 4a+b \pmod {26} $ and $10 \equiv 19a+b \pmod {26}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

$$9 \equiv 4a+b \pmod {26}$$

$$10 \equiv 19a+b \pmod {26}$$

How can I solve the following system?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried 
so far and where you are getting stuck so that someone can help you.
Just stating a question like this then it is likely it will get closed. This site uses 
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$17x+11y \equiv 7 \pmod {29}$ and $13x+10y \equiv 8 \pmod {29}$. What are x and y?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641998/17x11y-equiv-7-pmod-29-and-13x10y-equiv-8-pmod-29-what-are-x-and)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that substracting the two equations gives us that $15a \equiv 1 \pmod {26}$.

This gives us that $a \equiv 7 \pmod {26}$.

Since $4 \times 7+b \equiv 9 \equiv 35 \equiv 5 \times 7 \pmod {26}$, this implies that $b \equiv 7 \pmod {26}$.

The answer is $a \equiv b \equiv 7 \pmod {26}$.

Comment: I need to find the values of both a and b.

Comment: @r.d Didn't I provide you with it? You cannot find the exact values of $a$ and $b$, you can only find the values modulo 26.

Comment: I am solving an exercise which requires me to find the values of a and b without modulo

Comment: @r.d That is impossible, without no bounds. Notice that $7,7$ as well as $33, 33$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the system in matrix form:
$$
\pmatrix{4 & 1 \\ 19 & 1}
\pmatrix{a \\ b }
=
\pmatrix{9 \\ 10 }
$$
The determinant of the matrix is $-15$, which is invertible mod $26$, and so you can use Cramer's rule. In this $2\times 2$ case, it's easy:
$$
\pmatrix{4 & 1 \\ 19 & 1}^{-1}
=
-\frac{1}{15}
\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ -19 & 4}
=
-7
\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ -19 & 4}
\bmod 26
$$
and so
$$
\pmatrix{a \\ b }
=
-7
\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ -19 & 4}
\pmatrix{9 \\ 10 }
=
\pmatrix{7 \\ 7 }
\bmod 26
$$